# General solution of the equation $x_1 \cdots x_n + A = 0$ in complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let  $A \in \mathbb{C}$  be  a  nonzero  complex  number.

What  is  the  solution of $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5 + A = 0 $ in the  field of  complex  numbers $\mathbb{C}$ ? Or more  generally  the  solution  of
$x_1\cdots x_n + A = 0$  in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Thanks for  your attention guys :)

Comment: Are the $X_i$'s complex numbers too?  In that case, you can choose any non-zero $X_1, ... X_4$ and then solve for $X_5$.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: You can let $X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}$ be any nonzero complex numbers, and choose $X_n = -A/(X_1\cdots X_{n-1})$.

Comment: @Ted Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

*This CW post intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As remarked in the comments the general solution of $X_1\cdots X_n+A=0$ is 
$$\{(X_1,\dots, X_n)|X_1\neq 0,\dots, X_{n-1}\neq 0, X_n=-\frac{A}{X_1\cdots X_{n-1}}\}$$
This follows by observing that if one of the $X_i$ is zero, then because of $A$ being non-zero, this will never be a solution and in the case of all of them being non-zero solving for $X_n$.